# GCloud --filter with inequality in Powershell

Tags: powershell, gcloud

I'm trying to run the **GCloud cli** utility to find and then remove old docker images from a repository in **powershell**, but it doesn't like the inequality in the `--filter` and throws the error, "`The system cannot find the file specified`."

I've tried escaping the **'<'** with every escape char I could think of (powershell's grave **'`'** should have worked)

`gcloud container images list-tags gcr.io/myRepo/myImage --limit=99999 --filter="timestamp.datetime.date('%Y-%m-%d,Z') < '2019-06-01'" --sort-by TIMESTAMP --format='get(digest)`'

If I run this in `cmd.exe` and escape the **'<'** with **'^'** then it works great, but I can't seem to find a way to get the same result in powershell.

Comment: Oh yeah, and if I use '=' it works fine in powershell... Just not the inequalities '<' or '>'

Comment: You can always run it from a .bat file.

Comment: Familiar with `gcloud` but less familiar with PowerShell. Am I correct in thinking this is an issue with PowerShell's parsing of non-PowerShell commands? Or do you think the issue pertains to `gcloud`? One option (less elegant but more general-purpose) is to pump the results without the filter into a JSON parser and apply the filter on it then. Could you refactor the filter into a variable and apply the variable to the flag in the `gcloud ... --filter=$FILTER command? Would that work?

Comment: @DazWilkin Honestly I am at a loss as to why. `cmd.exe` shows the exact same error IF you do not escape the inequality (using a carat like this ^< ), but powershell seems to insist on doing something with that inequality even if I use the "stop parsing symbol" @BaconBits mentioned in the answer below...

Comment: Gcloud is gcloud.cmd, a .bat script, which makes this more complex.  I see the same problem within cmd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're calling any Powershell functions or commands in your command. I'd recommend using the [stop parsing symbol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-6), `--%`, which tells Powershell not to do anything with any of the remaining command and to pass it unparsed as an argument.

Try :

```
gcloud --% container images list-tags gcr.io/myRepo/myImage --limit=99999 --filter="timestamp.datetime.date('%Y-%m-%d,Z') < '2019-06-01'" --sort-by TIMESTAMP --format='get(digest)'
```

Comment: So with the comment @js2010 made about the `gcloud` util being a batch file I was able to deduce that I needed both the [stop parsing symbol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-6) AND the `cmd.exe` escape character to make it work. Here's the final result!
`gcloud --% container images list-tags gcr.io/myRepo/myImage --format=json --filter "timestamp.datetime.date('%Y-%m-%d,Z') ^< '2019-06-01'" --sort-by TIMESTAMP --format=get('digest')`

Comment: I think this is useful feedback to Google even if only for a footnote on `gcloud` documentation for PowerShell users. Please consider filing feedback using Google's Issue Tracker (for `gcloud`) [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187143&template=800102)

Comment: If someone is looking how to get ISO 8601 working with timestamps: `--filter="timestamp.datetime < -P4D" ` - gets records with timestamp older than 4 days.